# How to handle enter key in Javascript overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript overlay that consists of several input text search criteria. When the user presses the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in any of those inputs, I want to mimic the behaviour of the search button.

I know how to handle the enter key if there is only one input. I define the input as:

```
<input type=\"text\" class=\"txtOrgNmFilter inputBox\" onkeyup=\"ClientsListControl.onFilterKeyup(event);\" />
```

and in the onFilterKey up

```
onFilterKeyup: function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(".txtOrgNmFilter").click();
    }
}
```

My question is as follows: if I have several input texts, do I need to add the `onKeyUp` attribute in all of them or is there a simpler way (similar to a form submit action)?

My overlay is a table

Comment: Why do you escape your double quotes?

Comment: I escaped the double quote becasue I dynamically create the html in a C# code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('input').bind('keypress',function (event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13){
    $(this).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

With this you can bind the same event to all inputs (you can filter more if you want) and when someone clicks 'enter' with the focus on some this inputs, it will trigger the 'click' event.

Comment: That worked great, but I needed an `event.preventDefault()` inside the if loop in order to make the page not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the event handler to the container (the table). Then you can get the element that the key was actually pressed in (in prototype.js, use Event.findElement, but I'm sure other libraries have similar methods) and make one lot of logic depend on both that and the key pressed.

Comment: THanks I am gongi to try to use your method.

Comment: Sorry not to have answered earlier, I had to go out yesterday. I am not sure what you mean by "Attach the event handler to the table"?. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just include a `form` element, in which you define your `input`s? This way, the browser will by default submit the form when a user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> in one of the input fields.

And if you want to handle the search by yourself (e.g., using AJAX), you can catch the `submit` event of the form and perform the desired action. Doing so your form will still work if JavaScript is unavailable one way or another.

Comment: I tried that method but I cannot add a form becasue the overlay is already inside a form.

Comment: @user: But can't you add an `onsubmit` handler to the current form?

Comment: THe current form has already a on submit for the "main" Page, but I want to do handle the enter key for the overlay. THe "main" has several overlays, so I would have to know which one isa showing and it would be quite complicated ( I think).